# Android MediaRecorder kotlin record video with better quality

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Hi can you help me ? i want to record my android screen the code work but the video quality is bad
the code

```
try {
        mediaRecoder!!.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
        mediaRecoder!!.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE)
        mediaRecoder!!.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
        videoUri = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
            .toString()+ StringBuilder("/")
            .append(SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-hh_mm_ss").format(Date()))
            .append(".mp4")
            .toString()
        mediaRecoder!!.setOutputFile(videoUri)
        mediaRecoder!!.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_WIDTH )
        mediaRecoder!!.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264)
        mediaRecoder!!.setVideoEncodingBitRate(15000000)
        mediaRecoder!!.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
        mediaRecoder!!.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1280*720)
        mediaRecoder!!.setVideoFrameRate(30)
        val rotation = windowManager.defaultDisplay.rotation
        val orientation = ORIENTATION.get(rotation+90)
        mediaRecoder!!.setOrientationHint(orientation)
        mediaRecoder!!.prepare()
    }catch (e : IOException)
    {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set video encoding bitrate 2 times, and it finally sets the bitrate to 921600.

```
mediaRecoder!!.setVideoEncodingBitRate(15000000) // HERE
mediaRecoder!!.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
mediaRecoder!!.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1280*720) // AND HERE
```

Set it once to, for example, 3 million:

```
mediaRecoder!!.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000)
```

*And a little bonus advice: do not use `object!!.method()` or `object?.method()` that much. Try to avoid it as often as possible, because it goes against one of the main Kotlin features - Null Safety, it also makes your code pretty hard to read. Why wouldn't you instead write `mediaRecorder?.let{...}`*